# If Task queue failed at some queue then how can i inform to client some queue are failed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, task-queue

Hi i am using task queue for saving customer in customer entity. I am saving 10 customer into the customer entity using task queue. So Task in queue there are 10 customer. if due to some wrong inputs some 5 customer not saved in entity and 5 customer saved successfully in entity. so how can i inform these failed 5 customer information to client side.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to communicate between tasks and client side. The straight forward solution would be to query (poll) the server side for successful execution of your tasks.

**EDIT**:  if you don't need to let the client side know, and you just want to debug the problem and see what went wrong, you can simply view the logs. In the Developers Console go to **Monitoring** >> **Log** and search for the URL of your task. Updated answer accordingly

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment but just i want to know the some queue failed that information i need it how can i know failed queue information

Comment: You need to store somewhere the fact that something failed (or succeeded), say in Datastore, and then on the client side keep querying the server side until you get the failed/success result.

Comment: @VijayChougule if you don't need to let the client side know you can just view the logs. In the Developers Console go to **Monitoring** >> **Log** and search for the URL of your task. Updated answer accordingly